# Run non-blocking series of jobs

Tags: hadoop

A certain number of jobs needs to be executed in a sequence, such that result of one job is input to another. There's also a loop in one part of job chain. Currently, I'm running this sequency using wait for completition, but I'm going to start this sequence from web service, so I don't want to get stuck waiting for response. I wan't to start the sequence and return.

How can I do that, considering that job's depend on each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical approach I follow is to use Oozie work flow to chain the sequence of jobs with passing the dependent inputs to them accordingly.
I used a shell script to invoke the oozie job .

I am not sure about the loops within the oozie workflow. but the below link speaks about the way to implement loops within the workflow.Hope it might help you.

http://zapone.org/bernadette/2015/01/05/how-to-loop-in-oozie-using-sub-workflow/

Apart from this the JobControl class is also a good option if the jobs need to be in sequence and it requires less efforts to implement.It would be easy to do loop since it would be fully done with Java code.

http://gandhigeet.blogspot.com/2012/12/hadoop-mapreduce-chaining.html

https://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/how-to-chain-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Oozie is kind of heavy weight for the workflow I'm trying to perform. My workflow seems more low-level, so JobControl looks like a better solution. But how can I model a loop using JobControl?

Comment: @pera , welcome.. The main challenge to use loop over job chain is controlling the arguments to the job. Figure out a way to prepare the argument values of job inside loop by incremental fashion. hope you will definitely get the idea once you start the coding.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a pretty good idea, if I'm thinking the same thing. I could create a list of jobs where I will "unwrap" the jobs created in the loop and add them to JobControl as you said, it's only important to create good arguments. What do you think? I was also thinking about using Oozie to remove the job submission from the web service, but I don't know if I could have an Oozie workflow with only one Java class, in which I would create JobControl, like I would in web service...do you possibly know?

Comment: you are right, it would be easy if the jobs get the arguments which were arranged by some list/incrementer. And you can very well have a oozie workflow with single Java action, you may use the Java action tag.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, you have additional +1 from me :)